# Limit $(x,y)\to (0,0) (x^2 \cdot y^2)/(x^3 + y^3)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm not sure how to solve this problem.
As $(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)$, 
$$\frac{x^2\cdot y^2}{x^3+y^3} = L$$

With $y=ax$, I found $(a²x)/(a³+1)$ so $a$ cannot be -1. Does this prove the that limit does not exist?

I tried $y³= A(x)-x³$ and got nothing. Does the limit exist?

Sorry for any mistakes, English is not my native language.

Comment: What do you mean by $A(x)$?

Comment: No limit, the thing is not even defined when $y = -x.$ For a fraction, the denominator (in a lowest terms version) needs to be defined and nonzero near the origin.

Comment: I use it to try to found nice values and then I substitute A(x) for something like x²-x³, just a way to find a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Try to see what happens when y=-x, you should be able to proof that for any disc centered in (0,0), in that line there's no limit (the function is not even defined).

Comment: That was my doubt but i was not sure, thanks

Comment: This is what the OP has already done ($y=ax$ with $a=-1$).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Excepting that in that case $\frac{xa^2}{a^3+1}$ the denominator is 0...

Comment: @N.S.: Except what? The OP already noted in the question the $a=-1$ is impossible because the denominator is 0. I don't see that there's _any_ new information here, except a hint that asks the OP to do something he already describes how he did.